# Tracing a process using ptrace on Android ARM64

Tags: android, c, debugging, arm64, ptrace

I'm experiencing an infinite loop trying to trace simple hello world using ptrace() on Android ARM64 emulator that emulates AARCH64.  I'm not sure why it is not stopping.  I'm trying to trace a hello world program and get all executed instructions but it seems that this condition never returns false: `while (WIFSTOPPED(wait_status))`

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pid_t child_pid;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected a program name as argument\n");
        return -1;
    }

    child_pid = fork(); 

    if (child_pid == 0)
        run_target(argv[1]);
    else if (child_pid > 0)
        run_debugger(child_pid);
    else 
    {
        perror("fork");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}


void run_target(const char* programname)
{
    printf("target started. will run '%s'\n", programname);

    /* Allow tracing of this process */
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("ptrace");
        return;
    }

    /* Replace this process's image with the given program */
    execl(programname, programname, 0);
}

void run_debugger(pid_t child_pid)
{
    int wait_status;
    unsigned icounter = 0;
    printf("debugger started\n");

    /* Wait for child to stop on its first instruction */
    wait(&wait_status);

    while (WIFSTOPPED(wait_status)) 
    {
        icounter++;

        struct user_pt_regs regs;
        struct iovec io;
        io.iov_base = &regs;
        io.iov_len = sizeof(regs);


        if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGSET, child_pid, (void*)NT_PRSTATUS, (void*)&io) == -1)
            printf("BAD REGISTER REQUEST\n");

        unsigned instr = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, child_pid, regs.pc, 0);

        printf("icounter = %u.  PCP = 0x%08x.  instr = 0x%08x\n", icounter, regs.pc, instr);

        /* Make the child execute another instruction */
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_SINGLESTEP, child_pid, 0, 0) < 0) 
        {
            perror("ptrace");
            return;
        }

        /* Wait for child to stop on its next instruction */
        wait(&wait_status);
    }

    printf("the child executed %u instructions\n", icounter);
}
```

Comment: The only reason WIFSTOPPED would return false is if the process your are tracing has exited. Did it?

Comment: So I figured out the problem.  It did end,  just after a lot of instructions execute.  It's caught up in androids' bastardized fork() process.